# Type of vaccination proof required for traveling to Indonesia

Tags: covid-19, indonesia, vaccinations

Indonesia requires proof of covid vaccination for travel. Can travelers from the U.S. use this card as proof?

[image]

Comment: Last time I entered Indonesia (3 weeks ago), no one asked me anything about vaccine and I do not recall filling any form online or otherwise about it.

Comment: I guess that depends on the agent. All the documentation I've seen online says that a vaccination is required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've entered Indonesia in Feb and March 2023. In Feb 2023 (Jakarta) vaccination documentation was checked. The hand-written US CDC card(s) worked fine and were accepted without question. I don't recall the specific requirement but we have so many shots that we are on our second card so we always have "enough".

When entering in Denpasar in March 2023, no one wanted to see anything and there were no checks at the airport or anywhere else on Bali.

No idea whether there was a rule change or just local variability.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download their app. "Sehat Indonesiaku". It's their contact tracing app. You upload your vaccine card there (mine is the US one like in your picture), get the latest news, alerts, etc. Nobody asked me about my vaccination status when I visited back in March. But during transit from Taiwan, the airlines asked me if I have that app installed in my phone.